# Passing Java array into JSP file suing HashMap

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap

I'm trying to pass an arry into a new HashMap and then pass it into a jsp file. Problem is that it doesn't seem to be working. There is no output of my array on the jsp display. This is someof the code for the HashMap declaration.

```
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();

    for (int x = 0; x < nl3.getLength(); x++){
        Node currentItem3 = nl3.item(x);
        String key3 = currentItem3.getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue();
        if (requirement.equals(key3)) {
            matchingID[x] = build; 
            params.put("message", matchingID[x]);}}
```

My jsp file looks like this

```
    <%@ include file="/include.jsp" %>
<bs:page>

    <p>Please Input an Agent-Requirement</p>
    <form method="get" action="/QueueStat.html">
    Agent Requirement: <input type ="text" id='agentPram' name="requirement" value="${requirement}"/> <br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />

    List of Matching builds:
    <c:forEach items="${mathcingId}" var="mathcingId">
      <br><span class="mono mono-12px"><c:out value="${message}"/></span>
    </c:forEach>
  </jsp:attribute>
</bs:page>
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I suspect that the prams.put might be incorrect. Or maybe the jsp file?

Comment: Did you verify whether the `requirement.equals(key3)` condition is ever true? Basically, run this through a debugger.

Comment: Yes requirement.equals(key3) condition is true. I did a System.out.println(matchingID[x]); and it worked fine. Its when i added the HashMap that things stop working. @PiotrWilkin

Comment: Not sure if it matters, but you have a typo in your jsp: "mathcingId" instead of "matchingId".